# Derived table performance

Tags: sql-server, performance, derived-table

I have a table which has around 70 odd columns and a huge amount of data. If I just select only the required columns for a stored procedure and use it as a derived table, will it help in improve the performance than using the original table as it is?

Comment: What about view?

Comment: It depends. It's always good practice to not involve columns you don't need, if only because it makes your code more robust. Inside subqueries, the optimizer can see that columns go unused and leaving things out generally doesn't make a difference. For the final `SELECT`, taking only the columns you need is crucial because it allows for the most efficient selection of indexes and memory grants, and reduces the amount of data that has to be sent over the client. In other words: when in doubt, leave 'em out.

Comment: No idea, haven't seen the table or the stored procedure.  I would imagine that some sort of index would help though.